# jQuery: $.ajax is not executed while another page is loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, browser

I have a button that redirects to a page. The PHP script of the page I want to redirect to takes some minutes. While waiting for the PHP script I want a setInterval-scheduler to refresh content with jQ AJAX, but it doesn't seem to be executed while the redirection is loading. Any ideas?

Code:

```
heartbeatInterval = 10000;
$(document).ready(
    function() {

        console.log('Document got ready.')

        setInterval(function() {
            heartbeat();
        }, heartbeatInterval);
});

$('#button').click(function() {
    window.location.href = '/...';
});

function heartbeat() {

console.log('Heartbeat triggers.');

$.ajax({
    url : action_heartbeat,
    type : 'POST',
    data : 'test',
    success : function(response) {
        $('#status').css('color', 'green').html($('#status').html() + '<br>Connected:  ' + response);
        console.log('Heartbeat finishes.');
    },
    error : function(xhr, message) {
        $('#status').css('color', 'red').html($('#status').html() + '<br>Connection lost: ' + message);
    }
});

}
```

Comment: We have lot's of ideas. Do you want to share your code with us so that we can help you?

Comment: Please show us some code. Also the first thing I would investigate is why a page takes several minutes to run... And as I imagine your code is even sending several consecutive requests to that same script, making it run even slower...

Comment: The long PHP script is fine, it generated much stuff and some minutes are a nice performance. The PHP script I call as Ajax request is not the same. That one takes about 100ms.

Comment: I don't work with PHP, but in ASP.NET server-side processing of requests related to the same user session is serialized (not done in parallel) - it has to do with thread safety of the `Session` object. There is a way around if you let the framework know that a given request will not modify the `Session`.

Comment: I am getting misunderstood. However, I'll just open a new fast loading tab that displays content while the real page loads.

Comment: Oh, @Igor, you're right. PHP is blocking the Ajax request. It also doesn't work when I call Ajax in a second tab.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be possible. Note that PHP (server side) runs before any javascript (client side).

So You would need to have the PHP finish first. There may be a way to run the PHP in an iframe embedded in the page, which might allow for faster loading of the page that has the javascript you want to run in it.

Comment: Look at the snippet I added. I don't want to execute javascript from the target page. But when I click on the button the heartbeat function won't call any further Ajax requests.